# I can't connect to a web service http request failed err400

Tags: asp.net, database, web-services

I did use SQL Server Management Studio Express (free edition) to create my DB, Visual Studio Community (free edition) to create a web service SOAP through ASP.net (the WS just have 1 web method when you click it then show 5 empty fields), then i ran my WS in VS through option Debug in the Solution Configuration menu, after that the page open and i did check that my method insert the data in my DB and until here everything was correct, the data was inserted in the proper columns.

My problem start when i build the android app, the app have 5 empty fields that the user will fill and then send the info to the WS and put the data in the DB, but show me the next error:
                                                            **org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 400

at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call**

I read every thread about this problem, but none of that info solve my problem, i tried to make another project with 3 different variations but none of them work, i changed the localhost for my local ip, use 10.0.2.2:port, i add at the end "?wsdl", etc, etc.

I used SOAPUI to connect to test my WS, but when i try to connect from whatever location says me to did not found the page. Then i realized that maybe my App doesn't work because the WS only works for me and for nobody else, and need to put my WS in a real domain or something like that.

**I'm very noob in this world, but the real objective that i have is that my app can get/add data in a database on the internet, for the purpose that the users can see/add data, i dont know if this way is the correct for that goal.**

Any advice is welcome, please i'm searching info since 3 days ago and i cannot solve this.

Thanks in advance!

My android code is below:

```
package com.example.ejembd2;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private TextView txtResultado;
private Button btnins;
private EditText txtTit;
private EditText txtDes;
private EditText txtAco;
private EditText txtPal;
private EditText txtFec;
private TextView txtResultado2;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtCodigo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtReg);
    txtNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtVal);
    txtResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);

    btnInsertar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsertar);
    btnActualizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActualizar);
    btnEliminar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEliminar);
    btnConsultar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConsultar);

    btnins = (Button) findViewById(R.id.InsEnBD);
    txtTit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.T);
    txtDes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.D);
    txtAco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.A);
    txtPal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.P);
    txtFec = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.F);
    txtResultado2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultado2);

    btnins.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String a = txtTit.getText().toString();
            String b = txtDes.getText().toString();
            String c = txtAco.getText().toString();
            String d = txtPal.getText().toString();
            String f = txtFec.getText().toString();
            new insercion1().execute(a, b, c, d, f);
        }
    });
}



private class insercion1 extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        String a = params[0];
        String b = params[1];
        String c = params[2];
        String d = params[3];
        String f = params[4];

    boolean resul = true;

    final String NAMESPACE = "http://proof.net/";
    /*final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:50490/ServicioWebSoap/ServicioClientes.asmx"; //cambio*/
        final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:50490/ServicioClientes.asmx";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "NuevoEvento";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://proof.net/NuevoEvento";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("Titulo",a);
    request.addProperty("Descripcion",b);
    request.addProperty("Compania",c);
    request.addProperty("Palabras",d);
    request.addProperty("Fecha",f);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet=true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try

    {
        transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 
        Log.v("prueba1", ">>>>>>>>>");

        SoapPrimitive resultado_xml = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        String res = resultado_xml.toString(); 
        //My code in the .asmx return 1 if a row was added to the Table.

        if (!res.equals("1")) 
            resul = false;
    }

    catch(
    Exception e
    )

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        resul = false;
    }

    return resul;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {


        if (result)
            txtResultado.setText("Insertado OK");
        else
            txtResultado.setText("Error!");
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT1: WSDL (im only using the WebMethod "NuevoEvento")**

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://proof.net/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://proof.net/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://proof.net/">
<s:element name="NuevoEvento">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Titulo" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Descripcion" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Compania" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Palabras" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Fecha" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="NuevoEventoResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NuevoEventoResult" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="ListadoEventos">
<s:complexType/>
</s:element>
<s:element name="ListadoEventosResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ListadoEventosResult" type="tns:ArrayOfEventos"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfEventos">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Eventos" nillable="true" type="tns:Eventos"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="Eventos">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Titulo" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Descripcion" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Compania" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Palabras" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Fecha" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="NuevoEventoObjeto">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="evento" type="tns:Eventos"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="NuevoEventoObjetoResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NuevoEventoObjetoResult" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="NuevoEventoSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:NuevoEvento"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="NuevoEventoSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:NuevoEventoResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ListadoEventosSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ListadoEventos"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ListadoEventosSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ListadoEventosResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="NuevoEventoObjetoSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:NuevoEventoObjeto"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="NuevoEventoObjetoSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:NuevoEventoObjetoResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ServicioClientesSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="NuevoEvento">
<wsdl:input message="tns:NuevoEventoSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:NuevoEventoSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ListadoEventos">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ListadoEventosSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ListadoEventosSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="NuevoEventoObjeto">
<wsdl:input message="tns:NuevoEventoObjetoSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:NuevoEventoObjetoSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ServicioClientesSoap" type="tns:ServicioClientesSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="NuevoEvento">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://proof.net/NuevoEvento" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ListadoEventos">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://proof.net/ListadoEventos" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="NuevoEventoObjeto">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://proof.net/NuevoEventoObjeto" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="ServicioClientesSoap12" type="tns:ServicioClientesSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="NuevoEvento">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://proof.net/NuevoEvento" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ListadoEventos">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://proof.net/ListadoEventos" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="NuevoEventoObjeto">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://proof.net/NuevoEventoObjeto" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ServicioClientes">
<wsdl:port name="ServicioClientesSoap" binding="tns:ServicioClientesSoap">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:50490/ServicioClientes.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="ServicioClientesSoap12" binding="tns:ServicioClientesSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:50490/ServicioClientes.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**EDIT1: The data i posted to the service (only using the first webmethod)**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace ServicioWebSoap
{
/// <summary>
/// Descripción breve de ServicioClientes
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://proof.net/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// Para permitir que se llame a este servicio web desde un script, usando      ASP.NET AJAX, quite la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ServicioClientes : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public int NuevoEvento(string Titulo, string Descripcion, string   Compania, string Palabras, string Fecha)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data  Source=SRCOMPUTADOR\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=DBEventos;Integrated  Security=True");

        con.Open();

        string sql = "INSERT INTO Eventos (Titulo, Descripcion, Compania,  Palabras, Fecha) VALUES (@Titulo, @Descripcion, @Compania, @Palabras, @Fecha)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Titulo", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  Titulo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Descripcion",  System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Descripcion;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Compania", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Compania;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Palabras", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Palabras;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fecha", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Fecha;

        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        return res;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public Eventos[] ListadoEventos()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data  Source=SRCOMPUTADOR\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=DBEventos;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT id, Titulo, Descripcion, Compania, Palabras, Fecha FROM Eventos";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<Eventos> lista = new List<Eventos>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            lista.Add(
                new Eventos(reader.GetInt32(0),
                            reader.GetString(1),
                            reader.GetString(2),
                            reader.GetString(3),
                            reader.GetString(4),
                            reader.GetString(5)));
        }

        con.Close();

        return lista.ToArray();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public int NuevoEventoObjeto(Eventos evento)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SRCOMPUTADOR\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=DBEventos;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();

        string sql = "INSERT INTO Eventos (Titulo, Descripcion, Compania, Palabras, Fecha) VALUES (@Titulo, @Descripcion, @Compania, @Palabras, @Fecha)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Titulo", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = evento.Titulo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Descripcion", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = evento.Descripcion;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Compania", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = evento.Compania;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Palabras", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = evento.Palabras;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fecha", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = evento.Fecha;

        int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        return res;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 400 means bad request - show us the wsdl and then show us what data that you posted to the service.

Comment: There it is the info you requested @takendarkk, however i'm not very sure if you were asking for the code in VS when you put the phrase "data that you posted to the service", anyways i hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was my suposition; the WS only was a emulation (doesnt exist in the web), the solution was solved following the next steps:

1. Publish it with VS and making use of IIS Manager.
2. If problems arise with the WS, follow the instructions that support.microsoft.com deliver really works (i searched for days and the key was there).
3. Then in the URL for the HttpTransportSE call use your local ip substituting "localhost".